# How to Implement off chain Keepers for Decentralize Perpetual Exchanges like GMX.io?

Tags: solidity, oracles, decentralized-exchange, off-chain

I'm attempting to clone gmx.io. I understand most of the on-chain and Dex concepts, but I'm stumped on how to establish an off-chain Keepers they did not opensource the code for that, so could you kindly assist me in determining what the specific usage of the keepers was and how I would implement keepers?

I've included some relevant articles below.

https://gmxio.gitbook.io/gmx/contracts
https://gmx-io.notion.site/gmx-io/GMX-Technical-Overview-47fc5ed832e243afb9e97e8a4a036353
https://medium.com/perpdex/gmx-research-9da560f1e447
https://liamhieuvu.com/how-gmx-limit-order-and-long-short-work

Answer (score 0):

I found another open-source project that has implemented a keeper similar to gmx. I believe it could be helpful for you.
This is the link :
https://github.com/Buffer-Finance/Buffer-Keepers